# secure plain text password in process creation windows security log event

Tags: windows, security, password-protection, event-log, installutil

I have a batch script with this command in it

**installutil   /account=user /Password=password /config="ServiceConfig.xml" /LogFile="ex.InstallLog" "Hosting.exe"**

When i run the script in commandLine i have a creation process with ID 4688 logged in windows security logs with a password in plain text in IT .

How can i proceed to not show plain text password in the security logs?

I can't turn off the windows logs because they are used by the security team in my company and  i can not use the local service credentials so i have to set it this way to be able to use the automated script .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to not show the password in plain text.

I have tested, and using this part in the scripts, I don't see the password in the event viewer.

First, save it as follows:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$cred | Export-CliXml -Path "PATH\Cred.xml"
```

Then, use it in the scripts as follows:

```
$cred = Import-CliXml -Path $credPath
```

So far, I have not seen it again in plain text.

The exported credentials are only valid on the machine that generated the file and with the user that generated them.

Comment: that script does not replace $cred with the password at the end anyway?